# How to load Spring applicationContext into Jersey Application

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, jersey

I'm creating a Jersey JAX-RS web service with the following:

```
package com.mycompany.rest.config;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


@ApplicationPath("")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestResourceClasses();
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> getRestResourceClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
        resources.add(com.mycompany.rest.controllers.UserController.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

However, when I try and integrate a spring applicationContext such as the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.rest.user"/>


    <bean id="userService" class="com.mycompany.rest.user.UserServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

I get null pointers from my controller class for the userService being loaded by the bean pasted above. I'm assuming this is because the application context is not being loaded into the Jersey application.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inject Spring beans into your Jersey resource classes, you need to add jersey-spring3 dependency to your class path. see https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/spring.html

An hello-world example can be found at https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.19/examples/helloworld-spring-webapp

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the link. But there seems to be a problem with the pom file. I'm getting an error when I try and do mvn package. That error is : Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar': Invalid JDK version in profile 'jdk1.7+': Unbounded range: [1.7, for project org.glassfish.jersey:project
  org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.19

Comment: @gstanley, not sure if it's still relevant, but I had similar issues, and resolved it by excluding specific transitive dependencies: `<dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId> <version>2.22.1</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> </exclusion> ... </exclusions> </dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and i fixed it by adding @autowired to my service, and extending SpringBeanAutowiringSupport like the following :

```
@Path("/mails")
public class MailController extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport{
@Autowired
private MailService mailService;

@GET
@Path("/{code}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public String getMails(@PathParam("code") String code) throws Exception {
    //function logic
}
```

Note that this is working without integrating  jersey-springx.jar
And I'm using Spring 3 along with jersey-bundle-1.19.1.jar